# Delete rows from dataframe if column value does not exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets, each with two columns (can be made into one column) and 1000s of rows.

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['07/05/2013 08:00', 1.871287], ['07/05/2013 08:15', 1.878118], ['07/05/2013 08:30', 1.882696], ['07/05/2013 08:45', 1.891523], ['07/05/2013 09:00', 1.876457]], columns=['C', 'D'])
B = pd.DataFrame([['07/05/2013 08:00', 0.942500], ['07/05/2013 08:15', 0.959445], ['07/05/2013 09:00', 0.975362], ['07/05/2013 09:15', 0.981597], ['07/05/2013 09:30', 0.987643]], columns=['E', 'F'])
```

One column is a timestamp, the other is a measurement. I need to correlate the two measurements, but one of the datasets has extra measurements.

I want the code to read one row from the first (full) dataset, check if there is a corresponding measurement in the second dataset made at the same date/time, and if not then delete the entire row from the first dataset. I want to repeat this for all rows in the first dataset.

Visual example:
[image: 1]

Would an `if` statement to check if the datetime of one df exists in the other, and keep the row if true but remove it if false, work? This seems inefficient. Could this process instead be achieved more efficiently through merges/joins, or some other way?

Comment: The data are in two separate csv files that I exported from Origin.
python: https://imgur.com/a/y3IO42S
Origin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vnGg.png

Comment: @Reti43 I have now added the data into the question, sorry.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in either of your data frames ? I think a simple inner join would work here or isin

Comment: @Manakin There are no duplicates. The data I have are calculated values from measurements of two entirely different parameters made at 15 minute intervals with two different instruments. Measurements at some times were not made (equipment downtime, unsuitable weather conditions, etc)
isin did work though, following Vladimir Kulyashov's example --- thank you

Comment: @R_Dax Are your CSV files RFC 4180 compliant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question doesn't contain enough information. So I'll try to guess and show you a toy example.
If your using pandas then the solution would be:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in pd.date_range('1/1/2020', '3/1/2020')], columns=['date'])
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in pd.date_range('2/20/2020', '3/1/2020')], columns=['date'])

>>> df1.shape
out: (61, 1)

>>> df2.shape
out: (11, 1)

>>> df1.head()
out: 
        date
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-02
2 2020-01-03
3 2020-01-04
4 2020-01-05

>>> df2.head()
out:
        date
0 2020-02-20
1 2020-02-21
2 2020-02-22
3 2020-02-23
4 2020-02-24

>>> new_df = df1[df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]
>>> new_df
out: 
         date
50 2020-02-20
51 2020-02-21
52 2020-02-22
53 2020-02-23
54 2020-02-24
55 2020-02-25
56 2020-02-26
57 2020-02-27
58 2020-02-28
59 2020-02-29
60 2020-03-01

>>> new_df.shape
out: (11, 1)
```

Now in the "new_df" you will have only those dates which are contained in both dataframes

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough info. I have added the data to the question. Thank you for your example, but one column is missing from each dataset --- that's the problem I have. Each row has a date and a measurement; I want to keep the rows (date and measurement) from each dataset that have matching dates. Example: keep 07/05/2013 08:00 1.871287 since there is a measurement for this date/time in both datasets, but delete 07/05/2013 08:30  1.882696 because there is no corresponding measurement at the same time in dataset 2. Dataset 1 has the extra rows that need deleting.

Comment: Oh, then you need to merge both dataframes into one. Read about merge method in pandas docs.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: @VladimirKulyashov I've added the datasets in the question so you can replicate the results. `isin` should indeed suffice.